# Save notifications when rebooting

Tags: notifications

When you reboot an Android, all notifications are deleted. Is there a way to save the notifications and restore them after reboot?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a script with [SL4A](https://github.com/damonkohler/sl4a) for example to automate a task so that on shutdown/reboot of the device notifications are saved to a txt file in your home drive.

I don't have experience with it myself, but if anyone else knows a better way to automate a script on Android I'd be very interested too.

EDIT: On upon further research what you want is a notification logger app, such as [Notification Log](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.hcilab.projects.nlog&hl=en&gl=US) which records your notifications locally and enables you to browse/export them at will.  Another possible app is [Notification History Log](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ikvaesolutions.notificationhistorylog&hl=en&gl=US)

Comment: Notification Log is great. Thank you so much. Notification History Log is a pay app so I never try it.